# Is there an attributive word for "to become a classic"?

Tags: word-request

What kind of attributive word (it could contain a hyphen) exists to describe the action of (more as a quality) "becoming a classic"?

For example:

> It's a ____________ heart-warming story for the whole family about how people react to things which are different from others.

Comment: Keep in mind that the term ‘classic’ isn’t always objective, and may vary depending on the perspective.

Comment: The question is a little unclear to me, since you ask for an attributive word, like an adjective, but your gloss is "to become a classic" - and that is a verb (or a clause).  Perhaps if you gave an example sentence with a gap, and a gloss of what you want it to mean.

Comment: @JamesK I wrote like verb because I don't know how to describe it using an adjective. This world is used to describe a movie that will become a classic (it is not necessarily true, but it's just written like that in movie description).

Comment: Perhaps if you gave an example sentence with a gap, and a gloss of what you want it to mean

Comment: "It's a ... heart-warming story for the whole family about how people react to things which are different from others." Those ... is where that word about "becoming a classic" should be.

Comment: @Silvija I've added your example sentence to your question. In future, rather than adding it as a comment, you can do this yourself with the small "Edit" button right under the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that there is a concise adjective that would go into that blank. We sometimes call something a "classic in the making" or say that it is "on its way to becoming a classic".

Comment: I didn't see  your answer but posted mine with the hyphens, so I will leave it up.

Comment: @Lambie I didn't see yours either! It said yours was posted 35 seconds earlier, but I left mine because it includes a second option. I think both of our answers are good.

Comment: Ah, no worries. [I left Manhattan after 9/11, couldn't stand it anymore. :)] Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Some context would help, but if you are speaking about contemporary media, there are expressions like "best-selling", or "hit", which indicate a book or a movie etc has been popular and successful:

- He is the author of a best-selling book.
- He is the star of a hit movie.

It depends on your definition of what a 'classic' is, but in media, most things that go on to be considered classic have had an impact on popular culture and have continued to do so after some time. There are other contexts where 'classic' may have a strict definition, such as in [motoring](https://www.wcshipping.com/blog/classics-cars-vs-vintage-vs-antique) where a 'classic car' is apparently one between 20 and 45 years old.

Comment: The context is right. I was talking about a movie. I guess these words fit, but it should mean that it will become a classic overtime (or it will have an impact or will be a hit, like you said). Somehow I think that there is some phrase or hyphen with words "future" or "to-be" or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

It's a heart-warming, **classic-in-the making** story for the whole family about how people react to things which are different from others.

classic in the making is very used. If before the noun, it would have hyphens.